# How to apply validation for email id text box in window phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to apply validation to text box.
How to apply validation for email id text box in window phone 7?

Answer (score 6):

```
 public static bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
   {
       // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
       return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, 
              @"^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))" + 
              @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$"); 
   }



using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your email TextBox's InputScope property to EmailNameAddress 
and use this

```
Match match = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$").Match(txtEmail.Text);

if (match.Success)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Valid Email");
}    else    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [change the **InputScope** property of the textbox into **EmailNameAddress**](http://windowsphoneguy.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/working-with-on-screen-keyboard-in-windows-phone-7/)

Comment: It is best to set inputScope.. it will change On-Screen Keyboard layout what about validation, it will care of it?

Comment: Well, that's roughly the Step #1. Second step is to handle invalid characters? Should the application be idiot-proof?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Say the text box's name as txtEmail

    using System;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    private void txtEmail_Validating(object sender, 
                    System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       string errorMsg;
       if(!ValidEmailAddress(txtEmail.Text, out errorMsg))
       {
          // Cancel the event and select the text to be corrected by the user.
          e.Cancel = true;
          txtEmail.Select(0, txtEmail.Text.Length);

          // Set the ErrorProvider error with the text to display.  
          this.errorProvider1.SetError(txtEmail, errorMsg);
       }
    }

    private void txtEmail_Validated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       // If all conditions have been met, clear the ErrorProvider of errors.
       errorProvider1.SetError(txtEmail, "");
    }
    public bool ValidEmailAddress(string emailAddress, out string errorMessage)
    {
       // Confirm that the e-mail address string is not empty. 
       if(emailAddress.Length == 0)
       {
          errorMessage = "e-mail address is required.";
             return false;
       }

 // Confirm that the e-mail address in correct regex format
if (Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, 
              @"^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))" + 
              @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$")==false)

       // Confirm that there is an "@" and a "." in the e-mail address, and in the correct order.
       if(emailAddress.IndexOf("@") > -1)
       {
          if(emailAddress.IndexOf(".", emailAddress.IndexOf("@") ) > emailAddress.IndexOf("@") )
          {
             errorMessage = "";
             return true;
          }
       }

       errorMessage = "e-mail address must be valid e-mail address format.\n" +
          "For example 'someone@example.com' ";
          return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                return false;
            var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*");
            return regex.IsMatch(email) && !email.EndsWith(".");

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper method like below :

```
private bool IsVaildEmail(string email)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z");
    }
```

Call this method and pass the email id which returns true if matched and false if unmatched. Simple.